# tesseract/tesjeract crashes application upon instantiation

Tags: java, dll, crash, ocr, tesseract

I'd like to use tesseract in Java as I need to perform OCR for my ImageJ plugins. Therefore I am using the Java wrapper "tesjeract". However, when I instantiate `new Tesjeract("eng")` ImageJ crashes without giving any information.

Loading the libraries seems to be working, because when I don't instantiate `new Tesjeract("eng")` and run the same plugin twice, the second time I receive an `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library C:\Windows\System32\tessdll.dll already loaded in another classloader`.

Any ideas, what I can do to solve the problem?

In case it is relevant, I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, but have configured ImageJ to use 32-bit JVM, since tesseract is only available as 32-bit dll. I'm loading the dlls in a static block and both of them are placed in C:\Windows\System32 folder.

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("tessdll");
    System.loadLibrary("tesjeract");
}
```

Edit:

If found out that someone was experiencing a similar problem in c++, and the solution was that the languange files were missing. I suppose that's the problem in my case as well.

This is how the directory should look like ( found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/browse_thread/thread/68e6fa33e38264eb/8d260926c4b743d6?lnk=gst&q=program#8d260926c4b743d6) ):

```
project.exe
tessdll.dll
tessdata ----- eng.DangAmbigs
            |- eng.freq-dawg
            |- eng.inttemp
            |- eng.normproto
            |- eng.pffmtable
            |- eng.unicharset
            |- eng.user-words
             - eng.word-dawg
```

ImageJ is configured to use `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`. So I placed my dlls including the tessdata folder in the same directory and deleted the dlls from System32. Still, the application crashes.

Answer (score 1):

*.traineddata is language data for tess 3.x. You'll need ones for 2.x, such as [tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) .

Comment: now my tessdata folder looks exactly as described above, but it still crashes.

Comment: If still UnsatisfiedLinkError, make sure the .dll files are in the path that the program is looking for. If you still have problem, you may want to take a look at Tess4J, which is another Java wrapper and may be easier to use. http://tess4j.sf.net

Comment: the dll location is fine. When I execute my plugin and only load the libraries without executing any code I don't receive any error. `new Tesjeract("eng")` is causing the problem. But now that the correct language files are available I don't see what else the problem could be.